# Why CyclicBarrier doesn't always work as intended in my program?

Tags: concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I made a simple program that counts the sum of rows in a matrix. I wanted to do that concurrently so I used a CyclicBarrier. Sometimes it works as intended, but sometimes there are small mistakes, as if a program missed one or two numbers.

Here is my code:

```
package synchronizacja;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;
public class SumyWierszamiSekwencyjnie {
private static final int ROWS = 10;
private static final int COLUMNS = 100;
private static  int sum;
private static CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(COLUMNS, new Tmp());

private static class Tmp implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
}

private static class CountByColumns implements Runnable {
    private void CriticalSection(int wiersz) {
        sum += wiersz;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
           CriticalSection(i);
           try { barrier.await(); }
           catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Exception"); }
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
        new Thread(new CountByColumns()).start();
    }
}
}
```

The output should be

```
The sum is: 0
The sum is: 100
The sum is: 200
The sum is: 300
The sum is: 400
The sum is: 500
The sum is: 600
The sum is: 700
The sum is: 800
The sum is: 900
```

And sometimes it is, but more often than not it shows something like

```
The sum is: 0
The sum is: 100
The sum is: 200
The sum is: 297
The sum is: 400
The sum is: 500
The sum is: 600
The sum is: 700
The sum is: 800
The sum is: 900
```

Why does it happen? I was thinking it is maybe because run() in Tmp class doesn't have to be atomic, so the current thread may skip to counting sum of another row before setting sum to 0. If this is it, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

> I was thinking it is maybe because run() in Tmp class doesn't have to be atomic, so the current thread may skip to counting sum of another row before setting sum to 0.

I don't think so, [the javadoc of CB.await](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#await()) specifies

> If the current thread is the last thread to arrive, and a non-null barrier action was supplied in the constructor, then the current thread runs the action before allowing the other threads to continue.

There are two problems, the first is a potential multicore visibility
The thread executing the barrier action might not see the change in sum yet because it isn't updated in the core local cache.
Additially the += operator is not atomic so it might read a 20 from sum adds its "2" to it and writes 22 to sum even if another thread changed the value to 23 in between the read and write.
To fix both problems you need to use AtomicInteger or Varhandles (volatile only fixes the visibility problem. [Here are more information about atomic variables](https://www.baeldung.com/java-atomic-variables)